# If $x_1<x_2$ are local extremum points of $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, then $|f(x_1)|>|f(x_2)|.$

Tags: calculus

## Problem

Denote $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x},x>0.$ Let $x_1,x_2 $ be any two local extremum points of $f(x)$. Prove that if $x_1<x_2$, then $|f(x_1)|>|f(x_2)|.$

## Note

I have obtained that：

**1.** $|f(x)|=\dfrac{|\sin x|}{x} \leq \dfrac{1}{x};$

**2.** There exists one and only one local extremum point over every interval $(k\pi,(k+1)\pi)$, where $k=1,2,\cdots.$

**3.** $f'(x)=\dfrac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}.$ If $x_0$ is the local extremum point, then $x_0\cos x_0=\sin x_0$. Thus, $f(x_0)=\dfrac{\sin x_0}{x_0}=\cos x_0.$

This will  help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ has a local extremum at $x_0> 0$ then
$$ 
f'(x_0) = 0 \implies \tan(x_0) = x_0 \, .
$$

(*Idea:* Use this relation to get an expression for $|f(x_0|$ 
that does not involve trigonometric functions anymore.)

Using the trigonometric identity
$$
 \sin(x) = \pm \frac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt{1 + \tan(x)^2}}
$$
we get that at a the local extremum $x_0$
$$
 \sin(x_0) = \pm \frac{x_0}{\sqrt{1 + x_0^2}}
$$
 and therefore
$$
  |f(x_0)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x_0^2}}  \, .
$$

The desired conclusion now follows because the right-hand side
is a (strictly) decreasing function of $x_0$.

Comment: good solution. thanks.